# Show properties of the right shift operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Hi guys I am working on a problem from Applied Analysis. For 
$$S(x)_k = x_{k-1}$$
1) The pointwise spectrum of S is empty

2) $ran(\lambda I-S) = \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ for $|\lambda| >1$

3) $ran(\lambda I-S) = \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ for $|\lambda| <1$

4) The spectrum of S consists of the unit circle $|\lambda| =1$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$

I can really use some help. My work So far:
1) Assume contradiction and let $\lambda \in \sigma_p(S) $ ie in the point wise spectrum. Then we have that 
$$S(x_1,x_2...) = \lambda (x_1,x_2,...)$$
but then we have that 
$(0,x_1,x_2,...) = \lambda(x_1,x_2,...)$
Thus $x_i = \lambda x_{i+1}$ but from there we get that $x = (0,0,0...)$ thus no such lambda exists.

2) My idea was to explore what happens to the standard basis under the operator 
$(\lambda I-S)(e^1)= (\lambda I-S)(1,0,0,0...) = (\lambda,1,0,0,0...)$
so for $e^k$

$(\lambda I-S)(e^k)= (\lambda I-S)(0,0,1,0...) = (0,0,\lambda,1,0,0...)$

Now I want to claim that $\{e_i\}$ is still a valid basis for $\ell^2$. This is what I have so far.

Comment: (2) and (3) suggest you are working on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$. However, the equation in the paragraph after (4) suggests you are working on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. Which is it?

Comment: Thank you for noting that, it is in $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$

Comment: If it is $l^{2}(\mathbb Z)$ then the definition of $S$ you have used in 1) is wrong.